# Terminal says permission denied

Tags: macbook-pro, usb

[image]

My external usb wont open or i cant do anything on it. I have tried to restore it using disk utility but i doesnt work either. PLease help me

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  Could you edit what you want the end goal to be? Reformat the drive? The `dd` command will do a great job of erasing things if you’re not careful, perhaps many things in some cases. Some have named it DD the destroyer of disks.

Comment: What happens if you run `open ~/Desktop/USB\ disk\ 4\ gb.dmg`?

Answer (score 4):

If I see your screen correctly, it's a syntax error. Your problem was you had the DMG file as the 'command'.

If disk2 is your destination (the 4.2gb disk), then the following should work for you.

First, make sure your command prompt has nothing typed by you in it, either press <kbd>Ctrl-C</kbd> or <kbd>Return</kbd> a couple times then:

```
sudo dd if=/Users/rabika_1/Desktop/USB\ disk\ 4\ gb.dmg of=/dev/rdisk2 bs=1m conv=sync
```

**That will erase disk2 (rdisk2) and replace it with whatever "USB disk 4 gb.dmg" is.**

You will need to enter your administrator or root password when it prompts you for it. You won't see any feedback until it's done, you'll be at another command prompt.

After that you should be set.

Now there is another way of doing this where you can see the progress, if you want, then use this command instead of the prior one:

```
sudo dd if=/Users/rabika_1/Desktop/USB\ disk\ 4\ gb.dmg of=/dev/rdisk2 bs=1m status=progress conv=sync
```

Answer (score -2):

Your user "rabika_1$ does not have user rights to that file.

Comment: The shell expects an executable but won't find one. Every rabika_1:staff 666 non-exec file will show this *permission denied* message.